# How to get a variable from angularfire, even though it is an observable?

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, observable, angularfire

So, I don't know anything about angular much less how to select a specific field from my DB as it comes in Observable.
Tried everywhere to see an example but to no avail.

I'm using angular + firebase, with the angularFire library. There are examples in the documentation that I couldn't adapt.

This is my code made by following it.

```
constructor( private aff: AngularFirestore, public crud: CrudService ) { 
this.prodCollection = aff.collection<Product>('prods');
this.prods = this.prodCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
  map(actions => actions.map(a => {
    const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Product;
    return { ...data };
  }))
);
console.log(this.prods);
}
```

[This is a message you receive on the console.
[Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yn6IE.png)

I need to get only one "variable", how can I do that? With data=> res => or any recommended

Comment: Recommend using the docs https://angular.io/guide/observables and going through tutorial if you haven’t already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... I managed to solve my problem by adapting the answers that were sent to me.
At first I had copied the direct example from the firabase documentation but I still couldn't transform the result into an array.

this is how it appears:

```
private itemsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Item>;


items: Observable<Item[]>;
```

to work properly I changed the array from Observable<Product[]> to Product[]

```
private prodCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Product>;

array!: Product[];
```

Then I used the first example sent by JSmith to complete the problem

I don't know if it's the correct way but it's my solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [subscribe](https://rxjs.dev/guide/subscription) to it.

```
this.prodCollection.snapshotChanges()
  .pipe(
    map(actions => actions.map(a => {
      const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Product;
      return { ...data };
    }))
 )
 .subscribe((data) => this.prods = data); // YMMV
```

Comment: Can I just use the subscribe part or should it remain the map part?

By the way, what is the purpose of doing this process?

Comment: `subscribe` is meant to be called after the `pipe()`.  About observables, please read [the documentation](https://rxjs.dev/guide/observable).

Answer (score 0):

as Matthieu Riegler told you need to subscribe.
This is not angular or firebase specific.

You can do it many ways but if my understanding is correct to retrieve the variable only one time and without needing to unsubscribe you could do;

```
this.prodCollection.snapshotChanges()
  .pipe(
    take( 1 ) // You only retrive value once
  ).subscribe( snapshot => {

     const data = <Product[]> a.payload.doc.data();

     this.prods = data;

   } );
```

using the `map` function helps you process the data before subscription, this can help you avoiding boilerplate code if you for example share the same observable across multiple components. This way you could do:

```
this.prodCollection.snapshotChanges()
  .pipe(
    take( 1 ) // You only retrive value once
    map( snapshot => ( snapshot.payload.doc.data() as Product[] ) )
  ).subscribe( ( data:Product[] ) => {

     this.prods = data;

   } );
```

Comment: Maybe it's a problem of my lack of knowledge, I did just as Matthieu Riegle and you explained. But it gives the following error,

` Type 'Product' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<Product[]>': source, operator, lift, subscribe, and 3 more.`

to store the data I created

`private prodCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Product>;
  prods: Observable<Product[]>; `

Comment: @PedroTartari I've added modifications